# Specifying msg.value in Ethers js in Front-End

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, react

I'm trying to call a smart contract function that gets three parameters, I also want to specify the msg.value in my front end to call this function using ethers js. I wanted to ask how I can achieve that, without msg.value, my code looks like this:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
const signer = provider.getSigner();
const contract = new ethers.Contract(myContractAddress, myContract.abi, signer);
const transaction = await contract.mySolFunction(a, b, c);
await transaction.wait()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass an `options` object as the last argument of your function:

```js
await contract.mySolFunction(a, b, c, {value: 5}); // what what ever value you need.
```

For example, in my case, for this contract:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.16;

contract Contract {

    uint256 public total;

    function get() public payable {
        total += msg.value;
    }

}
```

I have this `ethers.js` code:

```js
const ethers = require("ethers");

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("http://localhost:7545");

const abi = [
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "get",
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: "payable",
    type: "function",
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "total",
    outputs: [
      {
        internalType: "uint256",
        name: "",
        type: "uint256",
      },
    ],
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
  },
];

const contract = new ethers.Contract(
  "0x7058E9B5b6D97f7d299179f287FcD463fC793ec5",
  abi,
  provider.getSigner()
);

async function call() {
  const result = await contract.get({ value: 5 });
  console.log("result: ", result);
}

call();
```

The transaction receipt I got as the `result` is:

```js
{
  hash: '0x749dc5c0d9a14eae6bb9ba8cc53eeeb86306f61acbf1a59fa468db1227554628',
  type: 0,
  accessList: null,
  blockHash: '0x6507fe0fc032ceaf65713e792ca93acc12ff7326b0c2ca8c4288703291b6c5aa',
  blockNumber: 40,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  confirmations: 1,
  from: '0x77d90a54D32d373E186fEEd2BAeAa42Ba1c4f2aD',
  gasPrice: BigNumber { _hex: '0x04a817c800', _isBigNumber: true },
  gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0xa4d6', _isBigNumber: true },
  to: '0x7058E9B5b6D97f7d299179f287FcD463fC793ec5',
  value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x05', _isBigNumber: true },
  nonce: 39,
  data: '0x6d4ce63c',
  r: '0x1a88738a74aacb4267f110ba3b031a8279ed949f032fd207314fc014e78df282',
  s: '0x21d0a01ca65634431ac7396e84f102df2ccc3d79ec462da589483f62ec3d2b66',
  v: 38,
  creates: null,
  chainId: 1,
  wait: [Function]
}
```

And I checked the value:

[image]

It works!

Comment: Great! Thanks very much, that's exactly what I was looking for.